# How to implement Inversion of Control using Pure DI on a Console Application? (Without using IoC containers)

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I have an example application where I would like to use the concepts of Inversion of Control to inject dependencies into lower level classes. My example application is a gummy bear factory. The gummy bear factory is responsible for creating each individual Gummy Bear, Adding it to a "Mini-Travel Size" bag, then adding the correct number of mini-bags to the [larger package](https://us-east-2-02810029-view.menlosecurity.com/c/i/aHR0cHM6Ly9pNS53YWxtYXJ0aW1hZ2VzLmNvbS9hc3IvZGVmNzBjYTAtYjFiMS00MjAxLWFjNTQtNDk2OGZiM2ZlNjY3LjM2ZTYxMzgxNmFhMTg2OGIyYzgwNDg3MzFiYzBkOTRlLmpwZWc%7E).

The Gummy Bear factory is provided a configuration that could change each time the factory project is run. In my example, it is a static class but just imagine this was loaded from say a configuration text file or XML file instead of being hard coded. Therefore, I have no idea of knowing at compile time what the user is going request for the number of gummy bears in a bag and the number of mini travel sized bags in a package.

Therefore, I am confused about how to decouple the Gummy Factory's `AssembleProducts()` method from the concrete implementation of `GummyPackage`, `GummyBag`, and `GummyBear` classes.

I can't necessarily use constructor injection because I don't know exactly how many GummyBears will be required. How would one decouple this code using the notion of "Pure DI". Is there any way to do this without the use of an IoC container? In my real world application, I am unable to use any third party packages (i.e. - IoC containers such as Autofac).

This is what the Configuration looks like (remember, this could have been from a file):

```cs
public enum GummyFlavor { Cherry, Lemon, Orange, Pinapple, Apple, Strawberry }

public static class GummyBearPackageConfiguration
{
    // Number of travel size gummy "mini-bags" per package
    public static int NumberOfGummieBagsPerPackage { get; set; }

    // Number of gummies in each travel size bag
    public static int NumberOfGummiesPerBags { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the code:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Load the "Configuration" 
        GummyBearPackageConfiguration.NumberOfGummieBagsPerPackage = 24;
        GummyBearPackageConfiguration.NumberOfGummiesPerBags = 7;

        GummyFactory gummyFactory = new GummyFactory();
        IGummyPackage gummyPackage = gummyFactory.AssembleProducts();

        OpenPackage(gummyPackage);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void OpenPackage(IGummyPackage package)
    {
        // Iterate over the Gummies
        Console.WriteLine($"Opening Gummy Package: \n");
        foreach (GummyBag bag in package.GummyBags)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Opening Gummy Bag #{bag.BagNumber}");

            foreach (GummyBear bear in bag.GummyBears)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    $"Gummy Number {bear.GummyID} is {bear.flavor.ToString()} flavor");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Generic Factory Class:

```cs
public interface IFactory<T>
{
    T AssembleProducts();
}
public abstract class Factory<T> : IFactory<T>
{
    public abstract T AssembleProducts();
}
```

Gummy Factory:

```cs
public class GummyFactory : Factory<IGummyPackage>
{
    public override IGummyPackage AssembleProducts()
    {
        IGummyPackage gummyPackage = new GummyPackage();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        
        for (int i=1;i<=GummyBearPackageConfiguration.NumberOfGummieBagsPerPackage;i++)
        {
            IGummyBag gummyBag = new GummyBag();
            gummyBag.BagNumber = i;

            for (int b =1; b <= GummyBearPackageConfiguration.NumberOfGummiesPerBags;b++)
            {
                IGummyBear gummyBear = new GummyBear();
                gummyBear.GummyID = b;

                int flvr = rnd.Next(0, 5);
                gummyBear.flavor = (GummyFlavor)flvr; // Pick a random flavor 

                gummyBag.GummyBears.Add(gummyBear); // Add Bear to the bag
            }

            gummyPackage.GummyBags.Add(gummyBag); // Add Bag to the Package
        }

        return gummyPackage;
    }
}
```

Gummy Package:

```cs
public interface IGummyPackage
{
    List<IGummyBag> GummyBags { get; set; }
}

public class GummyPackage : IGummyPackage
{
    public GummyPackage()
    {
        GummyBags = new List<IGummyBag>();
    }

    public List<IGummyBag> GummyBags { get; set; }
}
```

Gummy Bag:

```cs
public interface IGummyBag
{
    List<IGummyBear> GummyBears { get; set; }

    int BagNumber { get; set; }
}

public class GummyBag : IGummyBag
{
    public GummyBag()
    {
        GummyBears = new List<IGummyBear>();
    }
    public List<IGummyBear> GummyBears { get; set; }

    public int BagNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Last but not least, the Gummy Bear:

```cs
public interface IGummyBear
{
    GummyFlavor flavor { get; set; }

    int GummyID { get; set; }
}

public class GummyBear : IGummyBear
{
     public GummyFlavor flavor { get; set; }

    public int GummyID { get; set; }
}
```

The `AssembleProducts()` class depends on the concrete implementations of a GummyPackage, GummyBag, and GummyBear. Say in the future, management wants to change over from using GummyBags to mini Gummy cardboard "Boxes" because of new environmental rules. In the above scenario, I would need to crack open the `GummyFactory.AssembleProducts()` logic and re-wire the class to use boxes instead of Bags.

Is there a way to move this dependency linking up a level in the object graph?

Comment: The primary reason for having a factory method is to call the correct constructor when some other service requires a new instance of something.

Comment: Right, so the issue I'm thinking of is that inside the `AssembleProducts()` method, I am "newing" up the concrete implementations of a GummyPackage, GummyBag, and GummyBear class. Does it make sense to use DI to somehow "inject" in these dependancies and can it be done without an add on IOC container package? For me I suppose the concept of the "GummyFactory" is the service that requires reference to new instances of GummyPackage, GummyBag, and GummyBears. What if later on I want to change to different concrete implementations? I am not sure if DI is the right solution to this "problem"?

Comment: Does your package need to know that it has bags in it? Does you bag need to know that it has gummy bears in it? Or should your "product assembly" be more general and data driven? Make sure you are using the right abstractions to allow for either current testing, or future requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The package, bag and gummy bear behave more like data models and do not really need backing abstractions.

As you described in your example

> Say in the future, management wants to change over from using GummyBags to mini Gummy cardboard "Boxes" because of new environmental rules.

Then design the model to reflect that possibility.

For example here are my refactored models for this example application

```
public class GummyPackage {
    public GummyPackage() {
        Containers = new List<GummyBearContainer>();
    }

    public List<GummyBearContainer> Containers { get; set; }
}

public class GummyBearContainer {
    public GummyBearContainer() {
        GummyBears = new List<GummyBear>();
    }
    public List<GummyBear> GummyBears { get; set; }
    public string ContainerType { get; set; }
    public int ContainerNumber { get; set; }
}

public class GummyBear {
    public GummyFlavor flavor { get; set; }
    public int GummyID { get; set; }
}
```

the configuration does not need to be static. It can be a simple data class instance as well that reflects the required configuration for the application.

```
public class PackageConfiguration { //run-time data
    public int NumberOfContainersPerPackage { get; set; } 
    public int NumberOfUnitsPerContainer { get; set; } 
    public string ContainerType { get; set; }
}
```

Where it is populated from is an implementation detail/concern that can be handled by the user/developer of the application.

The factory can now explicitly depend on what it needs to perform its function at run time.

```
public interface IFactory<TProduct, TConfiguration>
{
    TProduct AssembleProducts(TConfiguration configuration);
}

public abstract class Factory<TProduct, TConfiguration> : IFactory<TProduct, TConfiguration>
{
    public abstract TProduct AssembleProducts(TConfiguration configuration);
}

public interface IGummyFactory : IFactory<GummyPackage, PackageConfiguration> {

}

public class GummyFactory : Factory<GummyPackage, PackageConfiguration>, IGummyFactory {

    public override GummyPackage AssembleProducts(PackageConfiguration configuration) {
        GummyPackage gummyPackage = new GummyPackage();
        Random rnd = new Random();

        for (int i = 1; i <= configuration.NumberOfContainersPerPackage; i++) {
            GummyBearContainer container = new GummyBearContainer();
            container.ContainerNumber = i;
            container.ContainerType = configuration.ContainerType;

            for (int b = 1; b <= configuration.NumberOfUnitsPerContainer; b++) {
                GummyBear gummyBear = new GummyBear();
                gummyBear.GummyID = b;

                int flvr = rnd.Next(0, 5);
                gummyBear.flavor = (GummyFlavor)flvr; // Pick a random flavor 

                container.GummyBears.Add(gummyBear); // Add Bear to the container
            }

            gummyPackage.Containers.Add(container); // Add container to the Package
        }

        return gummyPackage;
    }
}
```

The fact that the package, container and gummy bears are created within the factory is an implementation concern and **not** really tight coupling since that relates to coupling to concrete dependencies (services) that apply functionality or behavior instead of simply storing run-time data.

This results in following `Program` after refactoring

```
class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        // Load the "Configuration" ...
        PackageConfiguration configuration = new PackageConfiguration {
            NumberOfContainersPerPackage = 24,
            NumberOfUnitsPerContainer = 7,
            ContainerType = "Bag",
        };

        IGummyFactory gummyFactory = new GummyFactory();
        GummyPackage gummyPackage = gummyFactory.AssembleProducts(configuration);

        OpenPackage(gummyPackage);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void OpenPackage(GummyPackage package) {
        // Iterate over the Gummies
        Console.WriteLine($"Opening Gummy Package: \n");
        foreach (GummyBearContainer item in package.Containers) {
            Console.WriteLine($"Opening Gummy {item.ContainerType} #{item.ContainerNumber}");

            foreach (GummyBear bear in item.GummyBears) {
                Console.WriteLine($"Gummy Number {bear.GummyID} is {bear.flavor.ToString()} flavor");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and changing to boxes is simply a matter of updating the configuration data source.

Comment: What's the advantage of having the `IGummyBearPackageConfiguration` abstraction opposed to having a simple `GummyBearPackageConfiguration` data class? Would you ever need multiple implementations of `IGummyBearPackageConfiguration`?

Comment: Nice, so now instead of being hard coded to a single "container", I could (based on configuration) change the container type string from a "bag" to some other new container. However, it looks like I am still locked into using the now new `GummyBearContainer` class. The class accepts a string, `ContainerType`, which defines what type of container it is. But say I needed to have a whole other derived class that included functionality which is specific to a certain type of container? For example, the method for opening a `Box` container is different from a `Bag`.

Comment: Therefore the hypothetical `GummyBearBox.Open()` method would be different from the `GummyBag.Open()` method. I guess in that situation I would just abstract `GummyBearContainer` into an interface. `IGummyBearContainer` and inject the specific container type I need into the `GummyFactory` class constructor.

Comment: @Steven at the time of writing up the answer I choose to abstract the configuration based on the mention by the OP about where the configuration was being loaded from. I saw that as an implementation detail and my mind immediately went to using an abstraction to wrap that concern. Based on your comment I see that it could have been a simple data class, and the loading of that data implemented in its own concern. Thank you for posing question. It made me think over the design.

Comment: @Hooplator15 I believe you are confusing the concepts involved. For me the container is data. You are now hypothetically applying functionality that could be implemented in its own service.

Comment: @Steven I also realize I latched on the Pure DI concept and basically forced it into the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you really can't use constructor injection then you could simply use Setter Injection this way :

```
var configuration = new GummyBearPackageConfiguration
{
    NumberOfGummieBagsPerPackage = 24,
    NumberOfGummiesPerBags = 7
};

GummyFactory gummyFactory = new GummyFactory();
gummyFactory.GummyBearPackageConfiguration = configuration;
IGummyPackage gummyPackage = gummyFactory.AssembleProducts();
```

GummyFactory could contain the following setter :

```
public GummyBearPackageConfiguration GummyBearPackageConfiguration { private get; set; }
```

> The AssembleProducts() class depends on the concrete implementations of a GummyPackage, GummyBag, and GummyBear. Say in the future, management wants to change over from using GummyBags to mini Gummy cardboard "Boxes" because of new environmental rules. In the above scenario, I would need to crack open the GummyFactory.AssembleProducts() logic and re-wire the class to use boxes instead of Bags.

I'm not sure that this is a problem in which dependency injection could help. You could create a new factory MiniGummyFactory for this case so that would not require to change the AssembleProducts() function.